# Check if bullet object has left the screen and remove from array

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a bullet system that creates and shoots bullets(ellipses) along the y axis. I want to check if the bullet has left the screen so that I can remove it from the bullets array but I'm not sure how to check that. The function edges() is used for checking if the bullet has left the screen. This class is referenced in another main class so there's no function setup() here.

```
class BulletSystem {

  constructor(){
    this.bullets = [];
    this.velocity = new createVector(0, -5);
    this.diam = 10;
  }

  run(){
      this.move();
      this.draw();
      this.edges();
  }

  fire(x, y){
    this.bullets.push(createVector(x,y));
  }

  //draws all bullets
  draw(){
    fill(255);
    for (var i=0; i<this.bullets.length; i++){
      ellipse(this.bullets[i].x, this.bullets[i].y, this.diam, this.diam);
    }
  }

  //updates the location of all bullets
  move(){
    for (var i=0; i<this.bullets.length; i++){
      this.bullets[i].y += this.velocity.y;
    }
  }

  //check if bullets leave the screen and remove them from the array
  edges(){
    if(this.bullets.y > window.innerHeight){
        this.bullets.splice(0, 1);  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you probably want to use `height` instead of `window.innerHeight`. The variable `height` is provided by p5js and gives you the height of your canvas which might be different from `window.innerHeight`.

Secondly your condition `if(this.bullets.y > window.innerHeight)` doesn't make sense since `this.bullets` is an array: it doesn't have a `y` property.

In all the other functions you iterate over the `this.bullets` array to act on each bullet object: Here you want to do the same thing, for example like this:

```
//check if bullets leave the screen and remove them from the array
edges(){
  let i=this.bullets.length - 1;
  while (i>=0) {
      if(this.bullets[i].y > height){
          this.bullets.splice(i, 1);  
      }
      i--;
  }
}
```

This will iterate over the array starting from the end, for each index check if the bullet is still in the canvas, remove it if needed and decrement the next index `i` to evaluate.

Comment: I tried this and the program just stops ends when the bulletsystem is called.

Comment: What error message do you get? Also this line `this.velocity = new createVector(0, -5);` is probably wrong since `createVector` is not a class you probably want `this.velocity = createVector(0, -5)`

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
    at BulletSystem.edges (bulletSystem.js:38)
    at BulletSystem.run (bulletSystem.js:12)
    at Spaceship.run (spaceship.js:13)
    at draw (sketch.js:27)
    at b.a.default.redraw (p5.min.js:3)
    at _draw (p5.min.js:3)'

Comment: Oh indeed I forgot a `- 1` in the initialization of `i` :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to remove the bullet from the array or it's not detecting the bullet moving out of the screen.

Comment: Ok, it will be hard for me to debug: You could add a log of the bullet position, of the value of `height` maybe reuse `window.innerHeight` if needed and log it's value too, then log if the code goes in the condition. This way you'll have an idea of what's wrong. My answer is just a generic way to remove items from an array you might need to make it fit your code.

Comment: Seems like it only detects if the second bullet fired goes out of the screen. It doesn't detect if the first bullet goes out of the screen. Do you know why?

Comment: Probably because of `while (i>=0) {` instead of `while (i>0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version you can refer to:

```
let bull = [];
let obs;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
 obs = 300;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  line(0,obs,width,obs);
  
  for (i = 0; i < bull.length; i++) {
    bull[i].show();
    bull[i].move();    
    if(bull[i].y < 0 || bull[i].y + bull[i].w>= obs)
      bull.splice(i,1);
  }
}

function keyTyped() {
  append(bull, new Bullets(mouseX, mouseY, 0, 1));
}


class Bullets {

  constructor(x, y, xdir, ydir) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = 10;
    this.xdir = xdir;
    this.ydir = ydir;
    this.speed = 3;
  }

  show() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.w);
  }

  move() {
    this.x += this.xdir * this.speed;
    this.y += this.ydir * this.speed;
  }
}
```

The bullets will be removed from the array once they hit the obstacle, which in this case is the line.